# Run external process with Run fails

Tags: external-calls

When trying to execute an external process named `sim.out` with `Run`, Mathematica returns a number (e.g., 35584), but does not run the process. Although I specified the path of the process absolutely it does not work. However the process is executed correctly when I set the working directory to the notebook's directory.

This does not work:

```
path = FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "sim.out"}];
Run[path]
```

This works as expected:

```
dir = SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
path = FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "sim.out"}];
Run[path]
```

The 2nd example returns 0 and evaluates `sim.out` correctly.

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: use `SystemOpen` for this looks more comfortable.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: It would probably help to state your operating system

Comment: Are you sure that the file you are trying to run exists?   Are you sure that it is executable?  Are you sure that it doesn't run? If yes, what evidence do you have? Maybe it runs but crashes immediately.  Also, what is the *precise* number that `Run` returns?  What is your operating system?

Comment: If the code was really 35602, that's 8b12 in hexadecimal.  According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5638651/695132) it means termination with SIGQUIT and that the core was dumped (assuming you're on some sort of unix).  I don't know what that means.

Comment: The number returned is 35584. I edited my post. I am running Linux Mint in a 64bit version.
@Szabolcs: I double checked it: The file does exist and I can execute it from the command line or when I add the line of code as mentioned above and set the directory to the notebook-directory. Any further suggestions?

Comment: We don't have enough information to be able to reproduce the problem.  My guess is that your program does run, perhaps you just don't realize it for some reason (e.g. it crashes).  Have you tried running other programs?  Other programs after copying them to the very same location as your `sim.out`? Make a small program which does nothing and exits with return code 1. `Run` should return 256 in that case.  Does it work?  Try running Mathematica in command line mode, use Run that way, and see if there are messages printed to the terminal.

Comment: Does your program depend on any aspect of the environment that Mathematica may change (such as the `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`)?  Maybe it doesn't find its libraries so it crashes.  Does your program expect input from stdin?  That's not allowed with Run. What would your program do if it gets no input?

Comment: I created a program exiting with 1 and Mathematica outputs 256 as you expected. I also copied another program to the same folder. While executing from the command line works fine, Mathematica again needs the additional line to set the notebookdirectory to execute the program. If this line is missing, mathematica returns 0 anyway but there is no evidence that the program is executed. My program depends on no such aspects of the environment. The program doesn't expect input from stdin.

Comment: I tried running mathematica from the command line. Mathematica returns 0 when I try to execute different programs, but there is no evidence that the program was executed. I specified the absolute file path for the `Run[]` command.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your original question.  I thought that running `sim.out` from Mathematica *never* worked.  You say that it does work if your current directory is the same as the location of `sim.out`.  What happens if you try to run `sim.out` from the terminal, using its absolute path, while your working directory is a different one?  For example, assuming that `sim.out` is not in your home directory, `cd ~` in a terminal, then try to run `sim.out` using it's full path (e.g.  typing `/home/arneh/simulation/sim.out`, or whatever is the location of `sim.out`).

Comment: I tried running sim.out from the terminal with absolute path specification and it returned an error: Couldn't access memory"... But it works when I set the directory with cd to the directory of sim.out. What does that mean?